# If $f^2=f$, then $f$ is of constant rank.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Let $f$ be a continuous function from $[0,1]$ to set of $n\times n$ matrices i.e. $M(n\times n,\mathbb{R})$ such that $f(t)^2=f(t)$ for all $t$. Then  $f(t)$ has a constant rank for all $t$.

The only thing that I was able to guess conclude here that $f(t)$ has two eigenvalues, namely $0$ and $1$ with the minimal polynomial $x^2-x$, as if the minimal polynomial is $x$ or $x-1$, we are done.

Now what to do afterwards?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take the *trace* of $f(t)$. It's continuous on the one hand and it is the sum of the eigenvalue $1$'s on the other hand, which is just the rank of $f(t) $.

Comment: I just wrote up a way more complicated answer and I kinda feel dumb now. Gonna post it nonetheless.

Comment: trace Is a continuous function and it’s discrete so it will be constant. Is it the reason?

Answer (score 5):

One way to do this is the following: A square matrix $A$ acting on a linear space $V$ with $A^2 = A$ is diagonalizable with $V = \ker A \oplus \operatorname{img} A$. See wikipedia on [projectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Properties_and_classification).

Next thing you need to know, is that you can write down a basis of the kernel of a matrix using polynomials of the matrix’ entries. (I think you can get this from [Cramer’s rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer's_rule#Finding_inverse_matrix) alone, but you can also see this by using Gauss elimination, which continuously messes up a matrix, and extracting a basis for the kernel of a matrix from its strict row echelon form). This implies that you can find a basis of eigenvectors of a diagonalizable matrix that polynomially varies in the entries of the matrix because a basis of eigenvectors for the eigenspace of a specific eigenvalue is really just a basis of the kernel of the characteristic matrix with that eigenvalue plugged it.

Hence, you can find a *continuous* map $g \colon ℝ → \operatorname{GL}_{n×n}(ℝ)$, such that $g(t)^-{1}f(t)g(t)$ is diagonal for all $t ∈ ℝ$. Now $g^{-1}fg$ is also continuous and has constant rank if and only if $f$ has.

So without loss of generally, you may assume that $f$ is constantly diagonal with only possible eigenvalues $0$ and $1$. So …

But, yeah, whatever: Looking at the trace is way cooler.

Comment: Regarding "Gauss elimination, which continuously messes up a matrix": This sounds to me like you're saying that the reduced echelon form of $A$ depends continuously on $A$. That's not so (if that's not what you meant you might want to clarify).

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich It’s what I meant to say. I now see my faulty reasoning. Do you know of a way to prove that one can find a basis of the kernel of a matrix that continuously varies in the matrix’ entries? Is it even true?